# How to save results of hostent in buffer and when calling it again it doesn't overwrite

Tags: c, sockets

I'm just wondering how to save the results of hostent in a temp buffer to process it knowing that if i called gethostbyname twice it overwrites the first call like this example

```
struct hostent* d = gethostbyname("www.google.com");
struct hostent* b = gethostbyname("www.youtube.com");
printf("%s",d->h_name);
printf("%s",b->h_name);
```

Output will be in twice

```
youtube-ui.l.google.com
youtube-ui.l.google.com
```

What i want to do that save the results of each in two seperate hostent and when get the h_name of each one i get the h_name of google.com and the h_name of [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) and doesn't overwrite each other

What i tried something like this and it doesn't work

```
struct hostent d = *(gethostbyname("www.google.com"));
struct hostent b = *(gethostbyname("www.youtube.com"));
printf("%s",d.h_name); // doesn't give an output
printf("%s",b.h_name); // gives youtube-ui.l.google.com
```

Comment: You can't just shallow copy that struct, it has internal pointers that need to be copied as well, like `h_name` in particular being `char*`. The usual usage involves transposing out what you need before making any additional calls.

Comment: According to [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html#DESCRIPTION) "The gethostbyname*() and gethostbyaddr*() functions are obsolete. Applications should use getaddrinfo(3) and getnameinfo(3) instead."